# Google Script for removing name from Activities list not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script for my sorority roster but I can't get it to work.

I want to be able to type the status of a girl and have the script remove her name from the Actives list to whatever designation she requires, unless she is graduating or transferring, then I just need it to copy her name on that page of the sheet. Here is what I have:

```
function onEdit() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Actives (not pending termination / resignation)
  // target sheet of move to named Other (non-active), Resignation Pending, or Termination Pending
  // test column with status is col 4 or D
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
  if (s.getName() == "Actives (not pending termination/resignation)" &&
    r.getColumn() == d && r.getValue() == "resigned") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName() == "Resignation Pending";
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Actives (not pending termination/resignation)" &&
    r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "transferred") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getColumn(i);
    var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName() == "Other (non-active)";
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Actives (not pending termination/resignation)" &&
    r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "offcampus") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getColumn(e);
    var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName() == "Other (non-active)";
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Actives (not pending termination/resignation)" &&
    r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "inactive") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getColumn(a);
    var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName() == "Other (non-active)";
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Actives (not pending termination/resignation)" &&
    r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "term") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName() == "Termination pending";
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Actives (not pending termination/resignation)" &&
    r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "grad4") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName() == "Gradutating Seniors";
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Actives (not pending termination/resignation)" &&
    r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "grad5") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName() == "Fifth Year Seniors";
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

Comment: Two things: If you want column "D", you need to put it in quotes, otherwise it sees `d` as a variable that has no value. Second, your `target` variable is malformed. Change it to `var target = sheet.getSheetByName("Other (non-active)")` (and each accordingly down the function). You can also look at the Execution Transcript (View > Execution transcript) for errors that can help you debug.

Comment: Thank you! When I go to "View > Execution transcript" it just runs everything and completes the execution but when I try to run as an add-on nothing happens

Comment: @ElizabethFurtado It's looking for an Edit event. Go to the sheet, edit, and then look at the execution transcript to see if an error is highlighted.